# Deploying WPF Application with C++ DLL

Tags: wpf, deployment, icons, exe, publish

I want to the WPF interface and C++ algorithm together to generate an "exe"  file.
I have done: [WPF Deploying with C++ DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832020/wpf-deploying-with-c-dll)
**strong text**

1. I use VS ——  "Windows Installer Project" , 
   a. File system-create new shortcuts-attributes-icons.
   b. Right-click-output-EXE-select "shortcut for main output"-shortcut-drag to-desktop folder.
   c. Try—Quote—Source ICO—Icon—Wizard—Icon—Confirm.
   d, try-solution-default icon-not-custom icon-shortcut
   e,,,,, Right-click EXE-File Explorer-Manual-Create Shortcut
   -Will use-Correct-Custom icon-Shortcut
   f. Strange:—— VS (or installer)-the installation process cannot-perform-the same operation.**strong text**
2. I use the "build" menu-"publish" menu item, the generated "exe" file is installed on other computers, the error message is "Missing the necessary application file, contact the supplier", the installation fails.
3. I checked the deploy tool online. “InstallShield” is a commercial software. I used my mailbox to register for a trial, but I did not receive a reply email from another company. Is there a way to try it?
4. Can everyone tell me a good packaging method? Also help me solve the above problems, thank you.